# Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'n.compareTo(3)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'n'

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I have the following code:

```kotlin
val n = readln().toIntOrNull()
   
if (n > 3) {
   println(n)
}
```

I am receiving above subject error:

> Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'n.compareTo(3)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'n'.

However, if I write n == 3, I don't get the error. How to correct that without using `try{}` and `catch{}`?

I Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `n` cannot be more or less than 3 if it is null. What do you want to happen if it’s null?

Comment: `n` can be null. So is null greater than 3 or not?

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I cannot use toIntOrNull() here? Instead, I have to use toInt()?

Answer (score 0):

> How to correct that without using try{} and catch{}?

You can avoid that by making your call to `n` safe.

```kotlin
// If n is null, then you can return 0!
val n = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: 0

if (n > 3) {
    println(n)
}
```

Now, you no longer need to worry about `n` being `null`.
You can also handle it as an error:

```kotlin
val n = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: error("Not a Number")
```

Alas, it all depends on your requirements.

This is known as an "Elvis operator":

> When you have a nullable reference, b, you can say "if b is not null, use it, otherwise use some non-null value":
>
> `val l: Int = if (b != null) b.length else -1`
>
> Instead of writing the complete if expression, you can also express this with the Elvis operator ?::
>
> `val l = b?.length ?: -1`
>
> If the expression to the left of ?: is not null, the Elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right. Note that the expression on the right-hand side is evaluated only if the left-hand side is null.

To learn more about safe calls, see:

- [Kotlinlang - Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) (Highly recommend reading)

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much! I was using val n = readln().toIntOrNull() ?: "Enter Number Only" That did not work

Comment: You're welcome, it did not work because you converted the Int to String, so now you're no longer doing a numeric compare. If you wanted to error, then you can try: `error("Enter Number Only")`.